# C# Trying to retrieve %logonserver% from remote machine

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-7-x64

I've seen a couple examples here and there, here's what I'm trying to achieve. I know the below does not work, but essentially I'm trying to pull the %logonserver% from a remote machine. For some reason, the wmi query does not return any data.

```
try
{
 System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("\\\\"+txtboxMachineName.Text+"\\c$\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", "/c echo %logonserver%");
 startinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 startinfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 startinfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
 System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new Process();
 proc.StartInfo = startinfo;
 proc.Start();
 lblLogonServer.Text = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
catch
{
 lblLogonServer.Text = "Error has been encountered obtaining Logon Server";
}
```

Comment: Nothing? :( I'm thinking I should just use the above with psexec I guess..

Comment: A question that stumps stackoverflow?! :)